# React/Redux: Failed prop type - Invalid prop object

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

I've been trying to figure this problem out but can't get my head around it.

The fetch works fine but I'm receiving an error while mapping tasks from props.

JSON:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "uuid": "d5704a95-a7f4-441f-a962-70f3962ec137",
        "title": "Finish presentation task",
        "is_completed": false,
        "created_at": "2018-09-02T14:02:04+00:00",
        "url": "http://****/todos/d5704a95-a7f4-441f-a962-70f3962ec137"
    }
]
}
```

Now after the fetch the tasks are dispatched:

```
export const fetchTasks = () => dispatch => {
fetch('****', {
    headers: {
        "Authorization" : `****`,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(tasks =>
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_TASKS,
      payload: tasks
    })
  );
};
```

Followed by:

```
Tasks.propTypes = {
    fetchTasks: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    newTask: PropTypes.object
}
```

This returns me an error: *this.props.tasks.map is not a function*.

And on closer look: *Failed prop type: Invalid prop `tasks` of type `object` supplied to `Tasks`, expected `array`.*

Tried the following changes:

```
tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired
tasks: PropTypes.object.isRequired // array > object
```

Which still returned the same error.

Redux devtools shows the following in State:

```
{
    tasks: {
         items: {
            tasks: [
                     {
                        uuid: 'd5704a95-a7f4-441f-a962-70f3962ec137',
                        title: 'Finish presentation task',
                        is_completed: false,
                        created_at: '2018-09-02T14:02:04+00:00',
                        url: 'http://****/todos/d5704a95-a7f4-441f-a962-70f3962ec137'
                     }
                   ]
                },
       item: {}
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it `payload: tasks.data` ?

Comment: This resulted in:
    {
    tasks: {
       item: {}
      }
   }
     
But tasks.tasks fixed the problem, thank you!

Comment: yes... I did a typo in cooment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arup Rakshit pointed out:

```
.then(tasks =>
    dispatch({
    type: FETCH_TASKS,
    payload: tasks.tasks
    })
);
```

Fixed the problem!

Comment: I recommend you to avoid confusion use `data.tasks` and pass `data` as `then` arg.